# OpenGL C++ (Error thrown while making simple window)

Tags: c++, opengl

While creating a basic openGL window in c++ I get an error. I'm using GLFW and GLAD on Visual Studio 19, and i'm pretty sure my computer specs are good enough. I think I linked all my glfw files correctly and everything with Glad is properly attached.

> ```non
> The error: Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
>            violation executing location 0x00000000.
> ```

The full code I've written (some from tutorial). And yes, the includes are weird, but all includes are added correctly, I made sure. : `

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glad.h>                                       
#include <GLFW/khrplatform.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize GLAD.

Comment: have you tried debugging? You have a null pointer somewhere

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, any example on how I would do that? Because, I thought there was no function to init glad, only glfw.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, it'll show you exactly which pointer is null

Comment: Make it not null?

Comment: @Coristat You have to init glad after making the context current: `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` `gladLoadGL();`

Comment: Likely the NULL pointer is `glGenBuffer` (or mostly other gl-call) which becomes not null after glad is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

U have to init glad :)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  // .. setup the context 
  if(!gladLoadGL()) 
  { 
   printf("Something went wrong!\n");    
   exit(-1); 
  } 
printf("OpenGL %d.%d\n",  GLVersion.major, GLVersion.minor);
 // .. render here .. 
}
```